# How to convert string(cointaining offset) to date/time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

```
2.5.0 :071 > "2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200".to_datetime
 => Sat, 16 Jun 2018 22:39:09 +0200 
2.5.0 :072 > "2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200".to_datetime.utc_offset
 => 7200 
2.5.0 :073 > "2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200".to_datetime.utc
 => 2018-06-16 20:39:09 UTC
```

How to convert now `2018-06-16 20:39:09 UTC` to `2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200` again

rails console when trying second solution

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 9869
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.0)
2.5.0 :001 > orig = "2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200".to_datetime
 => Sat, 16 Jun 2018 22:39:09 +0200 
2.5.0 :002 > orig_offset = orig.zone # => "+2:00"
 => "+02:00" 
2.5.0 :003 > 
2.5.0 :004 > new = orig.utc
 => 2018-06-16 20:39:09 UTC 
2.5.0 :005 > 
2.5.0 :006 > same_as_orig = new.change(offset: orig_offset)
 => 2018-06-16 20:39:09 +0200 
2.5.0 :007 > same_as_orig == orig # => true
 => false 
2.5.0 :008 >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing Rails, I will give a pure-Ruby answer (which may be of interest in its own right). For this reason, I cannot help with the extraction of the time zone name. I understand that can be done with Rails or by installing the [tzinfo](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo) gem.

We begin with a given string:

```
str = "2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200"
```

In Ruby we will need use of various methods from the classes [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html) and [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html), so we must `require 'time'` or `require 'date'` (not required by Rails, I am told). Note `DateTime.superclass #=> Date`.

```
require 'time'
```

The first step is to create a `DateTime` object from this string. Two ways of doing that are to use [DateTime::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) or [DateTime::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), the latter being the more demanding and therefore more reliable method.

```
dtp = DateTime.parse(str)
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-16T22:39:09+02:00 ((2458286j,74349s,0n),+7200s,2299161j)>
dt = DateTime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-16T22:39:09+02:00 ((2458286j,74349s,0n),+7200s,2299161j)>
```

Another approach is to convert the string to an array and then use [DateTime::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-new) or [Time::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-c-new):

```
*all_but_last, offset = str.split(/[- :]/)
  #=> ["2018", "06", "16", "22", "39", "09", "+0200"]
all_but_last
  #=> ["2018", "06", "16", "22", "39", "09"]
offset
  #=> "+02:00"
arr = [*all_but_last.map(&:to_i), offset.insert(-3, ':')]
  #=> [2018, 6, 16, 22, 39, 9, "+02:00"]
DateTime.new(*arr)
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-16T22:39:09+02:00 ((2458286j,74349s,0n),+7200s,2299161j)>
Time.new(*arr)
  #=> 2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200
```

For the time being, trust me that UTC times are in fact instances of `Time`.

Browsing the methods of the class `Time` we find that it provides all the methods we need to convert between UTC time and local time, namely [Time.gmtime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-gmtime), [Time#utc_offset](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-utc_offset) (aka, `gmt_offset`) and [Time#getlocal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-getlocal).

The next step, therefore, is to convert the `DateTime` object `dt` to a time object, using [DateTime#to_time](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_time):

```
t = dt.to_time
  #=> 2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200
```

We may now convert this `Time` instance to a UTC time:

```
ut = t.gmtime
 #=> 2018-06-16 20:39:09 UTC
```

My earlier assertion that UTC times are `Time` instances can now be confirmed:

```
ut.class
  #=> Time
```

To convert this back to a local time we must save the local time's UTC offset:

```
offset = t.utc_offset
  #=> 7200
```

This offset is measured in seconds for GMT (7200/3600 = 2 hours).

We may now compute the local time from `ut` and `offset`:

```
ut.getlocal(offset)
  #=> 2018-06-16 22:39:09 +0200
```